# asp. net web api authentication and authorization

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I am using mvc 4 web api project template. i have USERMASTER table which contains usename and password for different users. 
Now i dont know what authentication is for web api???? 
how to stop invalid users to access it? ?

Let's say i m using fiddler to call web api. at that moment how can i stop invalid user.( i mean using tool like fiddler we can call web api. so i can stop invalid call not made by the valid user)

Moreover,  i wish that user A can access only 5 web apis and user B can access  all web apis from my project.

Is it possible???

i know how to use web api.
but i dont know about authentication and authorization process.

please help me.

I m using angularjs to call web apis.

Comment: can you switch to MVC5/Web APi 2 ? as you have more options with Bearer token for example like in this "http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api"

Answer (score 0):

Yes all this is possible but you need to use ASP.NET Web API 2 (.NET framework 4.5) you can find detailed source code and blog posts [starting here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) including AngularJS Authentication using Web API, it should makes things clearer for you.